# Different type expected in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create a form using Symfony and Doctrine.
I created a Job class, and a table in mysql which relates to it, using Doctrine. It also made the JobType and JobController, and Routing facility.

I can access the index page, where the jobs are listed, but can't access the new entry page.

Here are the files used for creating the forms.

JobController.php

```
   <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Job;
use AppBundle\Form\JobType;

/**
 * Job controller.
 *
 * @Route("/job")
 */
class JobController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Job entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="job_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $jobs = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Job')->findAll();

        return $this->render('job/index.html.twig', array(
            'jobs' => $jobs,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Job entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="job_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $job = new Job();
        $jobType = new JobType();
        $form = $this->createForm($jobType, $job);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($job);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('job_show', array('id' => $job->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('job/new.html.twig', array(
            'job' => $job,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Job entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="job_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Job $job)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($job);

        return $this->render('job/show.html.twig', array(
            'job' => $job,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Job entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="job_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Job $job)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($job);
        $editForm = $this->createForm(new JobType(), $job);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($job);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('job_edit', array('id' => $job->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('job/edit.html.twig', array(
            'job' => $job,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Job entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="job_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Job $job)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($job);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($job);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('job_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Job entity.
     *
     * @param Job $job The Job entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Job $job)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('job_delete', array('id' => $job->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

JobType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class JobType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('category', 'string')
            ->add('type', 'string')
            ->add('company', 'string')
            ->add('logo', 'string')
            ->add('url', 'string')
            ->add('position', 'string')
            ->add('location', 'string')
            ->add('desciption', 'text')
            ->add('how_to_apply', 'text')
            ->add('token', 'string')
            ->add('is_public', 'boolean')
            ->add('is_activated', 'boolean')
            ->add('email', 'string')
            ->add('expires_at', 'datetime')
            ->add('created_at', 'datetime')
            ->add('updated_at', 'datetime')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(   
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Job'
        ));
    }   

    /**
     * Mandatory in Symfony2
     * Gets the unique name of this form.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'add_job';
    }
}
```

[This is the error I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg0Uk.png)
Thanks!

EDIT:
The content of app/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
```

Comment: could you show the service definition for the JobType

Comment: This is what I found in app/config/services.yml

`# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
`

Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: Consider updating the question itself (there is an edit button right under it) with the service definition.  As you see, comments don't format well.

Comment: It's clear from your code you don't have a JobType service which is fine.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.  You might try commenting all but one of the add statements just to simplify things.

Comment: I left just one add statement, and tried instead of 'string', 'text' and an empty statement as well, and the same error is returned. 

Judging by the error, it seems that instead of new JobType a string should be sent: 
`$form = $this->createForm(new JobType(), $job);`

Do you think it has anything to do with that?

Comment: Nope.  Passing a form type object as the first argument is perfectly fine.  The error message is confusing to say the least.  What version of S2 and php are you using?  Are you running in development mode?

Comment: If you wanted to check your project in to github then I'd be willing to take a look.  Have a bit of time before football starts.

Comment: It seems I am actually using Symfony 3.0.0-BETA1, and PHP 5.6

Comment: This is the link to github https://github.com/TheodorMoraru/FormsSymfony.git
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmmm.  I have not played with S3 yet.  Do you need to be using the bleeding edge?  S2.7 might be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new JobType(), $job);
```

This is no longer possible in Symfony 3. In Symfony 3, you always have to pass the fully-qualified class name for form types:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(JobType::class, $job);
```

Also, in your form type you're passing the type name instead of the FQCN of the type classes.

Symfony 3 has just released its first BETA, which means it's very bleeding edge. Also, there are almost zero tutorials for Symfony 3 yet (as it's so extremely bleeding edge). You're reading a Symfony 2 tutorial, so I recommend you to install Symfony 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Yep.  Just did some research.  Looks like lots of Form component changes in 3.0.

Comment: [SOLVED]
Yes, this was the issue. Thank you all! :)
I will start again with Symfony 2, just to be safe.

Comment: @TheodorMoraru please mark this answer as solved if it solved your question.